# Listen to channel matching the pattern on node redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am using `node-redis`. Everything is working. I am subscribing to only `specific` channel. But I am receiving message from every channels:

## Server Code:

```
socket.on('connection', function(client) {
        const subscribe = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1')
        subscribe.psubscribe('tracking_*');

        subscribe.on("error", function (err) {
            console.log("Error " + err);
        });

        subscribe.on("pmessage", function(pattern, channel, message) {
            client.send(message);
            log('msg', "received from channel #" + channel + " : " + message);
        });

        client.on('message', function(msg) {
            log('debug', msg);
        });

        client.on('disconnect', function() {
            log('warn', 'disconnecting from redis');
            subscribe.quit();
        })
```

## Client Code:

```
socket.on('connect', function(data){
        setStatus('connected');
        socket.emit('subscribe', {channel:'tracking_hi'});
      });
```

As you can see I am only subscribing to the `tracking_hi` channel but I am receiving message from all the channels out there. What is wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend better logging on the server side - you might accidentally be publishing to the tracking_hi channel. I don't see any publish calls here, so this is just a guess.

Comment: Yes, I looked into the server too. It seemed fine.

Comment: Since the posted client code appears correct, the likely source of the issue is the server. As we can't see the code for the 'client' object we can't confirm but I suspect your client.send is sending the message to every tracking_* channel. Perhaps modifying the *publish* call to log what channel it is sending *to* and checking the output.

Comment: I am `publishing` message to redis via `jedis` through Java. Let me update the question.